# O que fazer quando o autor de um post reverte uma edição aparentemente significativa?

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica, edição

Fiz uma [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/244533/revisions) em uma resposta, porém um tempo depois o autor reverteu, a edição que fiz foi significativa e não vejo motivos para voltar para a versão anterior.

A resposta em questão é essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/244533/53279

O que fazer nesses casos? Já comentei perguntando o motivo da reversão, mas não sei se isso seria o mais correto.

Comment: Como primeira abordagem, um comentário, não só neste como na maioria dos casos, será sempre o mais correcto.

Comment: Reverti para a sua edição, um moderador já tinha aprovado, o que pesa que a edição foi sim útil. Provavelmente ele reverteu sem querer, pois vi que ele rejeitou a edição, talvez por ser novo no site. De qualquer forma, o comentário alertando sempre é válido, e fazer a edição novamente.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Claramente o AR reverteu sem ter plena certeza do que está fazendo, então comentar perguntando do porquê da reversão é o melhor. Neste caso, como você alterou apenas a formatação, eu iria insistir e reverter a reversão para retornar à sua edição, colocando como comentário o questionamento sobre a reversão e explicando que foi apenas alterado a formatação para melhorar a leitura.

Em caso de alterar outras coisas além da formatação, acredito que o ideal seria apenas comentar, questionando o motivo, visto que a reversão poderia ter sido feita devido ao AR discordar de alguma modificação.